# Doctrine 2 setParameter not working on string

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Entity\User u where u.first_name = :name');

$query->setParameter('name', 'Fawad');
$users = $query->getResult();

foreach ($users as $items) {
   echo $items->getId() . " " . $items->getFirstName() . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: What do You have on `$query->getSql()` and `$query->getParameters()`? What exactly mean "not working on string"?

Comment: thnks for your comment prblm solved :)

Comment: Can you tell us what was the issue?